# Is there Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference System (ANFIS) library in python?

Tags: python, neural-network, fuzzy

I need implement ANFIS (Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference System) in Python. Do libraries or code to use?

Answer (score 1):

the python package `anfis` :) you can see here an example: https://github.com/twmeggs/anfis/blob/master/anfis/tests.py

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: i am sorry, i hust thought that this will help because the question was, which libraries to use